# Transformation that keeps the point $(1, 1)$ but raises the horizontal asymptote of the reciprocal function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, rational-functions

If we are given the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, we can change the horizontal asymptote by adding a constant to the function. For example, $g(x) = f(x) + 5$, makes the asymptote at $y = 5$.

How could we keep the point $(1, 1)$ on the function's curve, while still raising the asymptote. Of course, we should only be able to do this with $0 < c < 1$, where $c$ is the new vertical asymptote.

Comment: What kind of transformation are you allowing? Vertical and horizontal shiftings, reflections about axes, and stretching/shrinking? Using these kinds of transformations, you can obtain every function of the form $f(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ with $c\neq 0$ and $ad-bc\neq 0$. This gives you enough parameters to find the function you want.

Comment: Have you understood the comment of Taladris ? As you can assume without loss of generality that the equation of the curve is $y=\frac{ax+b}{x+d}$, constraining it to pass through point $(x,y)=(1,1)$ means that $1=\frac{a+b}{1+d}$ giving two independent (=arbitrary) parameters $a,b$ and a dependent one : $d=a+b-1$. Try for example $a=1,b=1 \implies d=1$, then $a=0, b=1 \implies d=0$.